# Can I use global operator new for a class having operator new overloaded?

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading

Suppose I have a class with overloaded `operator new`.

```
class Class {
public:
   void* operator new( size_t );
   void operator delete( void* );
};
```

Will objects of that class always be allocated with the overloaded `operator new` when I use `new Class()` or is it possible that the default `operator new` is used when `new Class()` construct appears in code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The overloaded `operator new` and `operator delete` will always be used unless you explicitly do something like this:

```
// Allocate using global new.
MyClass* my_object = ::new MyClass();

// Use object normally.
my_object->my_method();

// Deallocate using global delete.
::delete my_object;
```

Or, as a somewhat extreme illustrative example, something like this:

```
#include <new>

// Use global placement new to allocate in a buffer created by global new.
MyClass* my_object = ::new(::operator new(sizeof(MyClass))) MyClass()

// Use object normally.
my_object->my_method();

// Explicitly invoke destructor.
my_object->~MyClass();

// Explicitly deallocate memory.
::operator delete(my_object);
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 5):

Use scope-resolution operator (::) to call the global definition for `operator new`, otherwise it will always use the overloaded `operator new`, except ofcourse in case of `placement new operator` which is anyway not intended to be overloaded.

```
class Test {
public:
   void* operator new( size_t );
   void operator delete( void* );
};

int main()
{
Test* pTest1 = ::new Test();
Test* pTest2 = new Test();

/*
 do some stuff
*/

::delete pTest1;
delete pTest2;
return 0;
}
```

Note the use of corresponding definition for delete operator.

Comment: Btw, placement new can be overloaded - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675059/how-could-i-sensibly-overload-placement-operator-new

Comment: yep, i mean OP doesn't intend to overload it in his example.

Comment: @sharptooth, @GMan: Placement new *is* an overload of `new`.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible exception I can think of is placement new [(discussed here)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/222557/cs-placement-new), but that's a different syntax.