# How to override operator new that's already defined in namespace

Tags: c++, memory-management, operator-overloading

I am currently working on a game, based on Playground game engine, and I stumbled on a problem. I'm trying to implement some kind of memory pool for my game objects, but when I try to use placement new operator or to define my own new operator in game classes, the game won't compile, because of this part of code is in one of the game library files:

```
// Operator NEW can't be in the PF namespaces...

// Memory tracking allocation
inline void* __cdecl operator new(size_t nSize, const char * lpszFileName, int nLine)
{
    return TRACK_MEMORY( pf_malloc_dbg(nSize, lpszFileName, nLine) );
}
inline void* __cdecl operator new(size_t nSize)
{
    return TRACK_MEMORY( pf_malloc_dbg(nSize, "FileWithoutDEBUG_NEW", 0) );
}
inline void* __cdecl operator new[](size_t nSize, const char * lpszFileName, int nLine)
{
    return TRACK_MEMORY( pf_malloc_dbg(nSize, lpszFileName, nLine) );
}
inline void __cdecl operator delete(void* p, const char * lpszFileName, int nLine)
{
    (void)nLine ;
    (void)lpszFileName;
    pf_free_dbg(p);
}
inline void __cdecl operator delete[](void* p, const char * lpszFileName, int nLine)
{
    (void)nLine ;
    (void)lpszFileName;
    pf_free_dbg(p);
}
inline void __cdecl operator delete(void* p)
{
    pf_free_dbg(p);
}
inline void __cdecl operator delete[](void* p)
{
    pf_free_dbg(p);
}
```

This code is located in debug.h game library file, and it's included internaly in game namespace somewhere in library files, so I can't omit it from compiling. Code is used only in debug mode, not in release, but I would like to make everything work for both modes, to track errors easier. So when I try something like this in one of my classes:

```
static MemPool<sizeof(Foo)> Foo::memPool;

Foo *Foo::Create()
{
    Foo *ptr = new (memPool.Alloc()) Foo();
    return ptr;
}
```

I get this error: `error C2061: syntax error : identifier 'memPool'`. This isn't because `memPool` isn't declared or defined, but because definitions of `new` operator in debug.h. Or when I try something like this:

```
class Foo
{
    ...

    inline void* operator new(size_t nSize)
    {
        return malloc(sizeof(Foo));
    }

    ...
};
```

I get error: `error C2660: 'GameNamespace::Foo::operator new' : function does not take 3 arguments`

How could I resolve this issue?

Comment: take a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3677129/3140187)

Comment: My problem isn't why or how to use palcement new operator. I simply can't use (compile) placement new operator in my classes because they are already overriden in library file. That code is used in debug mode, and in release mode, when this part of code is not used, copiling goes without errors. I can't uninclude mentioned header file (it's incuded somewhere in the library files), and I can't override new operator again in my classes (I got errors).

Comment: Actually, the errors and the fact that it works in release mode indicate that there's something like `#define new something`. The declarations you show like `inline void* __cdecl operator new(size_t nSize, const char * lpszFileName, int nLine)` also indicate that. For example, it could be `#define new new(__FILE__, __LINE__)`, maybe with an intermediary step `#define new DEBUG_NEW`. Undefine that macro to be able to use placement new.

Comment: (Also, it's illegal to replace the placement allocation functions, see [new.delete.placement] in the C++ Standard)

Comment: Thank's a lot dyp, you're absolutely right. I don't know how I didn't notice that macro in code. It's working in debug mode also now.