# Placement new With Overloaded Ordinary new Operator

Tags: c++, new-operator

I have an object of type `MyType` that, for SSE reasons, needs to be 16-byte aligned.  So, I wrote an allocator and overloaded the `new` operators.  Methods in `MyType`:

```
inline static void* operator new(size_t size) {
    awesome::my_allocator<MyType,16> alloc;
    return alloc.allocate(size);
}
inline static void* operator new[](size_t size) { return operator new(size); }
inline static void operator delete(void* ptr) {
    awesome::my_allocator<MyType,16> alloc;
    alloc.deallocate(reinterpret_cast<MyType*>(ptr),0); //last arg ignored in my impl
}
inline static void operator delete[](void* ptr) { operator delete(ptr); }
```

Now, for cache-locality reasons, I need to copy-construct an instance into a particular piece of 64-byte-aligned memory:

```
void MyType::copy_into(uint8_t* ptr) const {
    new (reinterpret_cast<MyType*>(ptr)) MyType(*this);
}
```

GCC tells me:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘MyType::operator new(sizetype, MyType*)’
```

ICC tells me:

```
error : function "MyType::operator new" cannot be called with the given argument list
1>              argument types are: (unsigned __int64, MyType *)
```

---

As I understand it, the placement new operator is provided by the C++ implementation (or possibly by `<new>`, which I also tried `#include`ing?) and simply returns its argument (`new` makes memory *available*, and placement new is the programmer saying that the given memory is available).

Curiously, the error does *not* occur when the (ordinary!) new operators defined above are *not* in the class.  Indeed, `MyOtherType`, which doesn't define them, works just fine.

Question: what's going on?  How should I fix it?

Comment: Perhaps overload the new to take 2 params - operator new(size, align) - so that normal, 1 param news aren't affected.  This might get around the compiler complaining by letting it use the built in type.  throw vs nothrow overloading might be causing some issues as well.

Comment: Does all that happens in one translation unit?

Comment: Placement new is usually used for "placing an object in already allocated memory" perhaps you need to overload placement new operator to coincide with your implementation as well?

Comment: @AJG85 You [cannot overload placement new](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3677129/688624): _"§18.4.​1.3 Placement forms
These functions are reserved, a C++ program may not define functions that displace the versions in the Standard C++ library."_

Comment: Oh well, so much for that idea then ;-(

Comment: Side point: `copy_into()` could check that the given memory is 16-byte aligned. Too bad it can't check that the given memory is large enough.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since you have defined `operator new` in your class, you need to use the global `new` to use the placement version of it.

```
#include <new>

...

::new (reinterpret_cast<MyType*>(ptr)) MyType(*this);
```

Comment: Confirmed that this fixes the problem. As I understand it, there was an overload of `new` in the current namespace, and so it didn't check the global namespace to find the overload (placement `new`) that would have worked?

Comment: I wouldn't say "in the current namespace". I would say "in the  `class` itself". There are two steps involved in matching a function call - name lookup and overload resolution. If the name is found in a class or the enclosing namespace, then the lookup ends. If the lookup results in multiple functions, only then overload resolution comes into play.