# Overloading Global Placement New?

Tags: c++, c++11, g++, operator-overloading, placement-new

I read other posts (one example: [How could I sensibly overload placement operator new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3675059/how-could-i-sensibly-overload-placement-operator-new)) that C++ standard disallows overloading the global placement new.

GCC did throw an error when I defined:

```
void* operator new(size_t sz, void*) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

However, GCC allows me to define:

```
template <class T>
void* operator new(size_t sz, T t) {
    std::cout << __PRETTY_FUNCTION__ << std::endl;
}
```

I tried to use placement new and the function template above did get call.

How does it differ from replacing placement new?  What's the rationale that C++ standard forbids overloading global placement new?